# GetProperties with reflection should return also Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I am reading all properties of a certain type of a `List<T>` entities.

I get all properties I want except `Nullable<int>`

```
var properties = entities.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single()
.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
.Where( p => Type.GetTypeCode(p.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object).ToList();
```

How do I have to change my query to get also `Nullable<T>` types ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` will count as a `TypeCode.Object`, so you will need to change your query:

```
.Where( 
    p => Type.GetTypeCode(p.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object ||
    (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&  p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var properties1 = new List<PropertyInfo>();
        foreach (var p in entities.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(c: typeof(Nullable<>)) || Type.GetTypeCode(p.PropertyType) != TypeCode.Object) properties1.Add(p);
        }
```